# 301 redirect url based off of a category in the url

Tags: nginx, php, redirect, redirection, html

Does anyone know how to redirect a url that contains a parent category of a product? Basically I want to redirect a ton of products to a simple landing page that I created, so instead of making redirects for each product, I want to target the parent category (manufacturer) and redirect it to my one landing page.

So like these:

```
https://example.com/product/baader/baader-600/baader-600-belts/belt-rubber/
https://example.com/product/baader/baader-600/baader-600-belts/belt-urethane/
https://example.com/product/baader/baader-600/baader-600-parts/cover/
https://example.com/product/baader/baader-600/baader-600-parts/washer/
```

Would all redirect to this one landing page:

```
https://example.com/replacement-parts/baader/baader-600/
```

So I guess you would target anything that has "product/baader/baader-600/" and then ditch the last part of the url (/baader-600-belts/belt-rubber/)  and redirect it to "/replacement-parts/baader/baader-600/" I have no idea how to make sus a RewriteRule.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to ServerFault.

We don't need a complex rewrites to achieve it. The following would work...

```
location /product/baader/baader-600/ { return 302 /replacement-parts/baader/baader-600/; }
```

Rewrite equivalent...

```
rewrite ^/product/baader/baader-600/ http://example.com/replacement-parts/baader/baader-600/;
```

If you require 301 redirect, then here are the equivalents...

```
location /product/baader/baader-600/ { return 301 /replacement-parts/baader/baader-600/; }
rewrite ^/product/baader/baader-600/ /replacement-parts/baader/baader-600/ permanent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the manufacturer must be dynamic, then you could add such a rule.

```
location ~ /product/(.+) {
    rewrite ^.*(\/product\/)([\w|-]*)\/(.*)\/.*$ /replacement-parts/$2/$3 permanent;
}

Here $2 is a second match group for manufacturer, and $3 contains product part.
```